# Should this door opening have a header and supporting framing?

Tags: doors, framing, structural

I'm moving a door over about a foot on a wall that runs through the middle of my whole house. I have a friend helping out who insists that this is fine, but I am not so sure. Doesn't there need to be a header and cripple studs in there?

[image: Newly framed door that looks funky.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there needs to be a header there.

Right now, the two studs that were cut are just hanging there with no support, they might be fine right now but over time could begin to sag causing issues with your door.

Typically when framing a door you have a king stud on either side that goes from the bottom plate to the top plate, a trimmer that goes from the bottom plate to your header and then cripples above the doorway. You have a king stud on the left but nothing on the right. It would be advisable to have one on both sides even if that means you have to shift the door back over slightly.

I would cut the two floating cripples off, flush with the top of the double plate header that was originally there and then extended that dph all the way through to carry all of those cripples and add a king stud/trimmer on the right side.

Second, when moving doors it is easy to forget about how they will get cased out, running it tight up against that wall on the right leaves you very little room for trim, I would consider bumping it back over just a bit, that's your call though.

It's commendable that your friend is willing to help however this can be a dangerous game when you don't have a full grasp on how things should be built. Good for you for asking questions.

Comment: Will the OP also need king studs?

Comment: King studs are not necessarily needed if what the trimmers and header tie into provide adequate lateral stability. Otherwise, door operation will result in excessive wall movement. A double plate header doesn't meet modern standards. I would install at least a double 2x6 U header while everything's open.